# I'm having trouble organizing

Tags: java, code-organization

I've just learned about how to use different classes in java, but I don't clearly know how to. I was also wondering how to make a sufficient mechanic in my code to start and stop my game. Such as when someone enters something that you're not supposed to, so it will allow them to enter it again. Keep in mind I'm not finished with this little game.

```java
package Horror;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating a scanner to get user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Game Story | Introduction
        System.out.println("You find yourself in a car, but you have no idea how you got there. It's raining outside and you spot a house through your cold window. You see something in the glovebox.");
        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
        String contlol = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Choices:");
        System.out.println("'Leave'");
        System.out.println("'Open Glovebox'");
        String firstchoice = input.nextLine();
        //Choice of leaving the car without opening the glovebox
        if (firstchoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Leave")) {
            System.out.println("You get outside of the car. It's dark and rainy and you have no other choice than to enter the safest place that's closest to you. The house");
            System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
            String cont1 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Choices:");
            System.out.println("'Walk'");
            String in = input.nextLine();
            //Choice of Walking to the house
            if (in.equalsIgnoreCase("Walk")) {
                System.out.println("You begin to walk towards the house. The door creaks open, and you find yourself in a dusty, cold house. The house doens't seem like it has had anybody in it for years, and there is an upstairs and a kitchen.");
                System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                String cont2 = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Choices:");
                System.out.println("'Kitchen'");
                System.out.println("'Upstairs'");
                System.out.println("'Living Room'");
                String gimme = input.nextLine();
                if (gimme.equalsIgnoreCase("Kitchen")) {
                    System.out.println("You walk into the dark kitchen. You find a light switch to the side, and the room brightens up a tiny bit. You see that the stove is on. Someone is boiling water.");
                    System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                    String gay = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Choices");
                    System.out.println("'Run'");
                    System.out.println("'Stay'");
                    String utters = input.nextLine();
                    if (utters.equalsIgnoreCase("Run")) {
                        System.out.println("You run to the door helplessly. You find that the door is locked... From the outside.");
                        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                        String k = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Choices:");
                        System.out.println("'Upstairs'");
                        System.out.println("'Living Room'");
                        String kkk = input.nextLine();
                        if (kkk.equalsIgnoreCase("Upstairs")) {
                            System.out.println("As you start your journey upstairs, the stairs start creaking, and you hear someone. After a while, you convince yourself it was your imagination.");
                            System.out.println("Once you get upstairs, you find a bathroom, and a bedroom.");
                            System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                            String rape = input.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Choices:");
                            System.out.println("'Bathroom'");
                            System.out.println("'Bedroom'");
                        }
                    } else if (utters.equalsIgnoreCase("Stay")) {
                        System.out.println("You walk toward the boiling pot of water. Inside, you see someone, but not yourself...");
                        System.out.println("You turn around, but not quick enough to evade the knife that is being hurled at you. It sticks inside your heart.");
                        System.out.println("You start to slowly die, watching the creature above you stare down into your eyes.");
                        System.out.println("YOU LOSE. . .");
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (gimme.equalsIgnoreCase("Living Room")) {
                    System.out.println("You walk into the small, but somehow spacious living room. There is a television, ceiling fan, record player, couches, and other living room items.");
                    System.out.println("As soon as you walk into the living room, the telvesion turns on to a news channel, and the ceiling fan starts spinning.");
                    System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                    String dick = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Choices:");
                    System.out.println("'Run'");
                    System.out.println("'Investigate'");
                    String meme = input.nextLine();
                    if (meme.equalsIgnoreCase("Investigate")) {
                        System.out.println("You circle around the living room. You find a cassette tape inside the telveison. You hear something behind you.");
                        System.out.println("You turn around, but no one's there. You turn back around and the cassette tape is gone.");
                        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                        String gutknife = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Choices:");
                        System.out.println("'Upstairs'");
                        System.out.println("'Kitchen'");
                        String search = input.nextLine();
                        if (search.equalsIgnoreCase("Upstairs")) {
                            System.out.println("As you start your journey upstairs, the stairs start creaking, and you hear someone. After a while, you convince yourself it was your imagination.");
                            System.out.println("Once you get upstairs, you find a bathroom, and a bedroom.");
                            System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                            String rape = input.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Choices:");
                            System.out.println("'Bathroom'");
                            System.out.println("'Bedroom'");
                            String fight = input.nextLine();
                            if (fight.equalsIgnoreCase("Bathroom")) {
                                System.out.println("As you walk into the bathroom, you flip on the light switch. You find a sink, toilet, mirror, and a bath tub with the shower curtains covering it.");
                                System.out.println("You hear water dripping.");
                                System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                                String poop = input.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Choices:");
                                System.out.println("'Investigate'");
                                System.out.println("'Look in Mirror'");
                                String gimmedat = input.nextLine();
                            } else if (fight.equalsIgnoreCase("Bedroom")) {
                                System.out.println("You walk in to a roomy bedroom. You think to yourself that it must be the master bedroom. You start looking around.");
                                System.out.println("After inspecting the room for a few minutes, you find a bloody knife on the drawer, it's right next to a dead body lying next to you feet.");
                                System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                                String cont0101 = input.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Choices:");
                                System.out.println("'Scream'");
                                System.out.println("'Examine'");
                                String gaymemes = input.nextLine();
                                if (gaymemes.equalsIgnoreCase("Examine")) {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (gimme.equalsIgnoreCase("Upstairs")) {
                    System.out.println("As you start your journey upstairs, the stairs start creaking, and you hear someone. After a while, you convince yourself it was your imagination.");
                    System.out.println("Once you get upstairs, you find a bathroom, and a bedroom.");
                    System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                    String rape = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Choices:");
                    System.out.println("'Bathroom'");
                    System.out.println("'Bedroom'");
                    String xdd = input.nextLine();
                    if (xdd.equalsIgnoreCase("Bathroom")) {
                        System.out.println("As you walk into the bathroom, you flip on the light switch. You find a sink, toilet, mirror, and a bath tub with the shower curtains covering it.");
                        System.out.println("You hear water dripping.");
                        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                        String poop = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Choices:");
                        System.out.println("'Investigate'");
                        System.out.println("'Look in Mirror'");
                        String gimmedat = input.nextLine();
                    } else if (xdd.equalsIgnoreCase("Bedroom")) {
                        System.out.println("You walk in to a roomy bedroom. You think to yourself that it must be the master bedroom. You start looking around.");
                        System.out.println("After inspecting the room for a few minutes, you find a bloody knife on the drawer, it's right next to a dead body lying next to you feet.");
                        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                        String cont0101 = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Choices:");
                        System.out.println("'Scream'");
                        System.out.println("'Examine'");
                        String rapeme = input.nextLine();
                        if (rapeme.equalsIgnoreCase("Examine")) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (firstchoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Open Glovebox")) {
            System.out.println("You find a note in the glovebox. It reads: 'They've taken it away from me. They told me I was crazy. But I'll prove them wrong. I will take it back. I will make this right. You don't know me. But I am there. Watching.");
            System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
            String cont3 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Choices:");
            System.out.println("Leave");
            String getin = input.nextLine();
            if (getin.equalsIgnoreCase("Leave")) {
                System.out.println("You get outside of the car. It's dark and rainy and you have no other choice than to enter the safest place that's closest to you. The house");
                System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                String cont69 = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Choices:");
                System.out.println("'Walk'");
                String fat = input.nextLine();
                if (fat.equalsIgnoreCase("Walk")) {
                    System.out.println("You begin to walk towards the house. The door creaks open, and you find yourself in a dusty, cold house. The house doens't seem like it has had anybody in it for years, and there is an upstairs and a kitchen.");
                    System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                    String cont2 = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Choices:");
                    System.out.println("'Kitchen'");
                    System.out.println("'Upstairs'");
                    System.out.println("'Living Room'");
                    String gimme = input.nextLine();
                    if (gimme.equalsIgnoreCase("Kitchen")) {
                        System.out.println("You walk into the dark kitchen. You find a light switch to the side, and the room brightens up a tiny bit. You see that the stove is on. Someone is boiling water.");
                        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                        String gay = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Choices");
                        System.out.println("'Run'");
                        System.out.println("'Stay'");
                        String utters = input.nextLine();
                        if (utters.equalsIgnoreCase("Run")) {
                            System.out.println("You run to the door helplessly. You find that the door is locked... From the outside.");
                            System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                            String k = input.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Choices:");
                            System.out.println("'Upstairs'");
                            System.out.println("'Living Room'");
                            String kkk = input.nextLine();
                            if (kkk.equalsIgnoreCase("Upstairs")) {
                                System.out.println("As you start your journey upstairs, the stairs start creaking, and you hear someone. After a while, you convince yourself it was your imagination.");
                                System.out.println("Once you get upstairs, you find a bathroom, and a bedroom.");
                                System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                                String rape = input.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Choices:");
                                System.out.println("'Bathroom'");
                                System.out.println("'Bedroom'");
                                String xdd = input.nextLine();
                                if (xdd.equalsIgnoreCase("Bathroom")) {
                                    System.out.println("As you walk into the bathroom, you flip on the light switch. You find a sink, toilet, mirror, and a bath tub with the shower curtains covering it.");
                                    System.out.println("You hear water dripping.");
                                    System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                                    String poop = input.nextLine();
                                    System.out.println("Choices:");
                                    System.out.println("'Investigate'");
                                    System.out.println("'Look in Mirror'");
                                    String gimmedat = input.nextLine();
                                } else if (xdd.equalsIgnoreCase("Bedroom")) {
                                    System.out.println("You walk in to a roomy bedroom. You think to yourself that it must be the master bedroom. You start looking around.");
                                    System.out.println("After inspecting the room for a few minutes, you find a bloody knife on the drawer, it's right next to a dead body lying next to you feet.");
                                    System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                                    String cont0101 = input.nextLine();
                                    System.out.println("Choices:");
                                    System.out.println("'Scream'");
                                    System.out.println("'Examine'");
                                    String ugh = input.nextLine();
                                    if (ugh.equalsIgnoreCase("Examine")) {

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (utters.equalsIgnoreCase("Stay")) {
                            System.out.println("You walk toward the boiling pot of water. Inside, you see someone, but not yourself...");
                            System.out.println("You turn around, but not quick enough to evade the knife that is being hurled at you. It sticks inside your heart.");
                            System.out.println("You start to slowly die, watching the creature above you stare down into your eyes.");
                            System.out.println("YOU LOSE. . .");
                            return;
                        }
                    } else if (gimme.equalsIgnoreCase("Upstairs")) {
                        System.out.println("As you start your journey upstairs, the stairs start creaking, and you hear someone. After a while, you convince yourself it was your imagination.");
                        System.out.println("Once you get upstairs, you find a bathroom, and a bedroom.");
                        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                        String rape = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Choices:");
                        System.out.println("'Bathroom'");
                        System.out.println("'Bedroom'");
                        String xdd = input.nextLine();
                        if (xdd.equalsIgnoreCase("Bathroom")) {
                            System.out.println("As you walk into the bathroom, you flip on the light switch. You find a sink, toilet, mirror, and a bath tub with the shower curtains covering it.");
                            System.out.println("You hear water dripping.");
                            System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                            String poop = input.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Choices:");
                            System.out.println("'Investigate'");
                            System.out.println("'Look in Mirror'");
                            String gimmedat = input.nextLine();
                        }
                    } else if (gimme.equalsIgnoreCase("Living Room")) {
                        System.out.println("You walk into the small, but somehow spacious living room. There is a television, ceiling fan, record player, couches, and other living room items.");
                        System.out.println("As soon as you walk into the living room, the telvesion turns on to a news channel, and the ceiling fan starts spinning.");
                        System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                        String dick = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Choices:");
                        System.out.println("'Run'");
                        System.out.println("'Investigate'");
                        String meme = input.nextLine();
                        if (meme.equalsIgnoreCase("Investigate")) {
                            System.out.println("You circle around the living room. You find a cassette tape inside the telveison. You hear something behind you.");
                            System.out.println("You turn around, but no one's there. You turn back around and the cassette tape is gone.");
                            System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                            String gutknife = input.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Choices:");
                            System.out.println("'Upstairs'");
                            System.out.println("'Kitchen'");
                            String search = input.nextLine();
                            if (search.equalsIgnoreCase("Kitchen")) {
                                System.out.println("You walk into the dark kitchen. You find a light switch to the side, and the room brightens up a tiny bit. You see that the stove is on. Someone is boiling water.");
                                System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                                String gay = input.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Choices");
                                System.out.println("'Run'");
                                System.out.println("'Stay'");
                                String utters = input.nextLine();
                                if (utters.equalsIgnoreCase("Run")) {
                                    System.out.println("You run to the door helplessly. You find that the door is locked... From the outside.");
                                    System.out.println("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE. . .");
                                    String k = input.nextLine();
                                    System.out.println("Choices:");
                                    System.out.println("'Upstairs'");
                                    String kkk = input.nextLine();
                                } else if (utters.equalsIgnoreCase("Stay")) {
                                    System.out.println("You walk toward the boiling pot of water. Inside, you see someone, but not yourself...");
                                    System.out.println("You turn around, but not quick enough to evade the knife that is being hurled at you. It sticks inside your heart.");
                                    System.out.println("You start to slowly die, watching the creature above you stare down into your eyes.");
                                    System.out.println("YOU LOSE. . .");
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would look into refactoring concepts.  Most games are also done in some type of loop.  A while loop might be good here.

Comment: This question might be more on-topic at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I understand that most games are done in loops such as while loops, but I am a beginner and don't know how to make one.

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is basically a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine). You print something, then present some choices; the user enters one of those choices, and you move to a some different "state" (i.e. a different place), where you print something, present choices, move to a new state.... etc.

You can represent a state something like this:

```
class State {
  String message;
  Map<String, State> choices = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}
```

(Left intentionally bare, for clarity)

and construct some states like this:

```
State start = new State();
start.message = "You find yourself in a car...";

State leaveTheCar = new State();
leaveTheCar.message = "You get outside of the car...";

State openGlovebox = new State();
openGlovebox.message = "You find a note...";

State dead = new State();
dead.message = "You're dead.";
```

And join the states together like this:

```
start.choices.put("Leave", leaveTheCar);
start.choices.put("Open glovebox", openGlovebox);

leaveTheCar.choices.put("Get back in car", start);
leaveTheCar.choices.put("Blah", dead);

openGlovebox.choices.put("Bloo", dead);
```

So, you're saying that when you're at the start, you can choose "Leave", and you'll move to the "leave the car" state or the "open glovebox" state; and that you can get back in the car, or do something else that results in you dying.

You can draw this as a [state transition diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram), where "nodes" are the states, and "edges" are the choices:

[image]

You'll need to create a load of these `State` instances and join them together for your game above. But once you have, the logic to "play" is quite simple:

```
State state = start;
while (true) {
  System.out.println(state.message);
  if (state.choices.isEmpty()) {
    break;  // No choices: game over.
  }

  while (true) {  // Keep going until user enters a valid choice.
    System.out.println("Choices:");
    for (String key : state.choices.keySet()) {
      System.out.println("'%s'%n", key);
    }
    String choice = input.nextLine();
    if (state.choices.containsKey(choice)) {
      state = state.choices.get(choice);  // Go to the next state.
      break;
    }

    System.out.println("Choose again!");
  }
}
```

For a related but slightly different way to implement this, check out the [State design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: A lot of effort answering an essentially off-topic question (but +1).  Drawing a [State Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram) is the place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll definitely look into learning state diagrams.